# Binding first arraycontroller object

Tags: ember.js

I need to bind a property to the first element of an arraycontroller
Something like that:

firstEltBinding: 'myArrayController.elementAt(0)'

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
firstElementBinding: 'myArrayController.firstObject'
```

Comment: Indeed! You can use it in Handlebars :D